# Save functions in a session

Tags: sessions, functions

I have a function I wrote specifically for a certain session in vim. Manually redefining it every time I load the session is tedious. Is there any way custom functions can be saved with the session? If not, what're some options for speeding up reloading that function every time I load the session?

Comment: How about putting the function in a file with the same name as your session file but ending in `x.vim` as described in item 10 under `:help :mks`?

Comment: @garyjohn This is the solution I found most helpful (automatically loads the functions and ties them to that specific session). If you add it as answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the function in a file with the same name as your session file but ending in `x.vim` as described in item 10 under

```
:help mks
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the functions are something you don't want *all* the time, so you don't want them in your `.vimrc` file, you can define them in a separate file and use `:source filename` to load in the definitions.  This avoids the security issues of `set exrc` and loading untrusted files.

If the pathname to your functions file is irritatingly long, you could even define a function in your `.vimrc` just to call `:source /home/me/annoyingly/long/path/name/functionsfile`.

Comment: If my functions were more general use, this would be good, but they've all been very session specific so far. Good idea to keep in mind though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that “certain session” means “certain project” and “certain directory” I would try to use the per-project `.vimrc` file. To get vim to additionally read the `.vimrc` in the current directory, I have `set exrc` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I came across that as a potential solution, which led to a question about [the danger of `set exrc`](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/why-is-set-exrc-dangerous/5059#5059). The risk outweighs the usefulness of the solution for me, unfortunately.